# Cypher query with regex gives an error when used in Python

Tags: python, regex, neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher query that acts as a LIKE clause and it works fine when used directly in Neo4J.

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.username =~ '(?i).*SUBSTRING.*' RETURN u;
```

But as soon as the query is put in a string variable in python it gives an error.

Python Code:

```py
def get_search_results(self, user_input):
        query = "MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.username =~ '(?i).*{user_input}.*' RETURN u; "
        return graph.run(query, {"user_input": user_input}).data()
```

Gives error:

```
ClientError: SemanticError: Invalid Regex: Illegal repetition near index 5
(?i).*{user_input}.*
     ^
```

I've checked online to see if the regex is valid and it seems to work just fine. Is there something basic I'm just forgetting about python and the way it handles regex?

Answer (score 0):

The regex thinks you are trying to specify the number of times `.*` should be repeated. Try this out:

```
query = "MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.username =~ '(?i).*\{user_input\}.*' RETURN u; "
```

In regex, if you want to specify how many times a character say `a` should be repeated, you use `a{start, end}`, where the repetitions should be between `start` and `end`. The compiler thought you wanted to repeat `.*` multiple times, which is not allowed. So, you need to escape the braces.